# Laravel 5.4: Mail notifications not sending and no error

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.4

Hello I know that this topic has been shared a lot here but I went through all of the questions about it and I don't find any fixes for my issue :/

I try to send email for reset pwd and for welcome user but I don't receive any of them, there is no errors, no logs and when I try to put shi*** values in the .env and mail.php config file I don't get any error either.

Here's my code:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=ns0.ovh.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=contact@neuralia.co
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I tried with mail instead of smtp, with no value instead of tls or ssl...

Here's my mail.php file:

```
<?php

return [

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'ns0.ovh.net'),

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', '587'),

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'contact@neuralia.co'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'contact@neuralia.co'),
],

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', ''),

'username' => env('contact@neuralia.co'),

'password' => env('**********'),

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
 ],

];
```

If you have any idea for me to test I'll be pleased to read and try them, thanks

Comment: I don't believe this really justified marking as a duplicate.  This is asking for help with the Mail facade in Laravel, which unfortunately does not return any form of error codes.  As a result, while the answer listed in the heading is potentially useful, there's a definite problem beyond the PHP specific guidance listed in the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

How did you sent the emails?

Did you generate mailables with:

```
php artisan make:mail nameOfMailType
```

After that, mail could be sent (using Mail facade) from controller with something like:

```
Mail::to($someEmailAdress)->queue (new nameOfMailType($someParametersIfNeedIt));
```

Also, if you can, you should try if it's working unecrypted on port 25, just for testing.